# vtk filter for OpenFOAM

Tags: python, vtk, openfoam

I want to filter a pressure by thresholding using python-vtk

```
    import vtk
    filename = "a.foam"

    reader = vtk.vtkOpenFOAMReader()
    reader.SetFileName(filename)
    reader.CreateCellToPointOn()
    reader.DecomposePolyhedraOn()
    reader.EnableAllCellArrays()
    reader.Update()

    tArray = vtk_to_numpy(reader.GetTimeValues())
    reader.UpdateTimeStep(tArray[-1]) 
    reader.Update()

    filter_threshold = vtk.vtkThreshold()
    filter_threshold.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
```

how should I select "pressure" on filter class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetInputArrayToProcess` method.

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAlgorithm.html#a6bea16e1329609dbccce0ff8d2367484

Comment: Thanks It may be resolved

"""
filter_threshold = vtk.vtkThreshold()
filter_threshold.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

filter_threshold.ThresholdByLower(1.0)
filter_threshold.ThresholdByUpper(100.0)

FIELD_ASSOCIATION_POINTS = 0
filter_threshold.SetInputArrayToProcess(0,0,0,FIELD_ASSOCIATION_POINTS,"alpha")
filter_threshold.Update()
"""